# JSON dump big list containing dict, text, datetime and ints gives "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Tags: python, json, string, typeerror

Using Python 3.2 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit.

```
f = open("raw_data/results.json", "wb")
json.dump(dictio, f)
f.close()
```

Gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\calc_stats_friendly_data.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\calc_stats_friendly_data.py", line 18, in main
    json.dump(races, f)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I have no idea what goes wrong. Using pickle works fine! But I have to use JSON...
Tips for finding the problem? The list is big. Saving it with pickle it takes 56 MB.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're opening the file for binary writing. Open it using `"w"` as a mode only.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem. However it's very non-obvious to me why binary mode is a problem. I come from a C background and I made it a habit to always open files in binary mode (so I don't get any spurious transformations I don't want). Can someone explain?

Comment: If you open the file in binary mode you should write bytes in the file. If you open it withouth the binary flag you can write unicode data.